# Computing Jaccard index of similarity on rasters

Tags: r, gis, raster, similarity, vegan

I want to compute Jaccard index of similarity based on continuous quantities. I found the package `vegan` that can compute the Jaccard index for continuous cases based on Bray-Curtis measure through the function `vegdist`. I was able to do it by choosing the number of sites randomly and compute the Jaccard index between all pairs of the chosen sites and take the average after. This procedure takes a lot of time especially that I have many scenarios to treat. I wonder if there is a way to do it by using rasters directly (using all the non-NA pixels) without using binary maps in faisable time.

Comment: Yes, there is a way, but you have to write code to do it.

Comment: @JariOksanenN thank you for your reply. Do you have any example?